# c++ compile error: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'DateTimeAndZone' to 'const int'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am working on some simulation software in which I have an entity that is moving toward a particular locatin on a 2D map. While the entity is moving toward to location, I am trying to display some information about its movement- such as how long it will take to get there (TimeToGo- or TTG), its ETA, and the remaining distance that it has to travel (DistanceToGo or DTG).

I have the following function in my `DisplayTime.cpp` source file:

```
void TimeReadout::update(const TPEquipmentTime::DateTimeAndZone& dateTimeAndZone_, const bool convertToSavedZone_)
{
  ...
}
```

This function is used to update the value displayed on the GUI for the ETA of the entity at the location. I know that the function works correctly, as it is used in several places in the program and does what's expected in those places.

I am now trying to reuse that function (copy & paste) to update the TTG value

I am now trying to use the function in another source file: `Dialogue.cpp` in the following way:

```
pFlightPlanTTGReadout->update(fpTTG);
```

The variable `fpTTG` is of type `TPEquipmentTime::DateTimeAndZone`, and the `update()` function states takes a variable of type `const int`.

When I try to compile, I get the expected error:

> 'update' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'Time_Value' to 'const int'

However, when I look at the function that I have copied this bit of code from- it has done exactly what I'm trying to do with a (different) parameter, of the same type, i.e.

```
pFlightPlanETAReadout->update(fpETA);
```

where `fpETA` is a variable of type `TPEquipmentTime::DateTimeAndZone`

What am I missing here? Why is it that this works in the original function, but not in the function that I am writing, even though I am (trying to at least) doing the same thing, just with a different variable?

**EDIT 07/01/2015 @ 18:45**
I have just noticed a difference between the `update()` function call that I'm trying to use in my function, and the one used in the original function:

In the original:

```
pFlightPlanETAReadout->update(fpETA);
```

If I hover the cursor over `update`, two functions are displayed in the little dialogue box:

```
virutal void TimeReadout::update(void)

virtual void TimeReadout::update(const TPEquipmentTime::DateTimeAndZone & dateTimeAndZone_, const bool convertToSavedZone_ = true)
```

Whereas in my function:

```
pFlightPlanTTGReadout->update(fpTTG);
```

If I hover the cursor over 'update', the dialogue box just displays one function:

```
void ElapsedTimeReadout::update(const int total_seconds_)
```

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will be helpful here.

Comment: You have posted a member function definition that takes 2 parameters and a call that provides 1 argument to member function. So probably you have some other "update" somewhere declared that takes 1 parameter (that is int).

Comment: I would have thought that this is the function that is being used- since if I right click on the `update()` function that has `fpETA` as the parameter that it's being given, and click 'Go To Definition' that is the function definition that it takes me to... (I'm using Visual Studio 2008 as my IDE by the way). I did wonder about that (only using one parameter when there are two in the definition) myself... I can see that in the same .cpp file as that function definition, there is another 'empty' definition: `void update(void){};` - could it be that this is the one being used, and overladed?

Comment: Don't always rely on the IDE's 'Go To Definition'. Use it only as a hint. There are many cases when the IDE gets it wrong, especially when there are multiple functions with the same name.

Comment: I did have a look in the drop down list of functions for that source file, but there was only the one `update()` function there...

Answer (score 1):

Unless I am missing something... this is basic C++. 
As you have mentioned the function `pFlightPlanTTGReadout->update` takes an `int` parameter and you are passing something that is NOT an `int` and cannot be implicitly converted to an `int`.

In the original `pFlightPlanETAReadout->update(fpETA)` is the function parameter also an `int`?
If it is,

- the one possibility is that `DateTimeAndZone` in the original code has a conversion operator from `DateTimeAndZone` to `int`.
- the other possibility is that the original code has an overloaded `update` function that takes `DateTimeAndZone` as the parameter.

Comment: No- as mentioned in my OP, in the original `pFlightPlanETAReadout->update(fpETA);` the paramater is of the same type as the one I'm trying to pass to the function, i.e. `DateTimeAndZone`... I can't see an overloaded function anywhere, and if I right click the function call, and click 'Go To Defintion', that is the one that it takes me to...